# Summing cells in a row up to a given column number

Tags: microsoft-excel, cells

This has been puzzling me and I hope you lot can help me out.

I have a table of numbers, and I wish to sum all the values in a row up to a specified column number. Idea being I can change the 'sum up to number' and the sum total will automatically update to the given range. 
Below is a simplified sheet of what I am aiming for. 
I can do it manually on this example but my live sheet is bigger so having a simple formula would be much easier. 
[image]

I have had success at doing it with a load of if statements however this clearly isn't the most efficient method see below:

[image]

Thank you in advance, really appreciate any advice you give.

Jasper

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have a table of numbers, and I wish to **sum all the values in a row** up to a specified column number.

The above statement contradicts your example which sums only alternating columns in a row starting with column C.

To sum all the values in a row try,

```
=sum(b5:index(b5:k5, 1, match(a$2, a$4:j$4, 0)))
```

To sum alternating values in a row try,

```
=sumproduct((c5:index(c5:k5, 1, match(a$2, b$4:j$4, 0))), --isodd(column(c5:index(c5:k5, 1, match(a$2, b$4:j$4, 0)))))
```

[image]

Comment: Great does exactly as I wanted. Thank you